# Wordpress AJAX not returning custom author meta

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Right now, I'm trying to retrieve custom author meta using AJAX for when a user clicks on the author's name.

What's going on is that my AJAX is not returning anything.

I've tested the variable I'm sending, and that is filled correctly, but I am not getting any response from Wordpress.

Any help would be appreciated.

To note, the PHP is in my `functions.php` file where there is another function that creates and saves the custom author meta field that I need to access the info from

Thank you,

Hunter

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request', 'student_meta_info');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_request', 'student_meta_info');

function get_student_meta_info()
{
    $studentID = $_POST['studentID'];

    $review = the_author_meta('review', $id);
    $weightloss = the_author_meta('weightloss', $id);
    $gained = the_author_meta('gained', $id);

    $AuthMeta = array("review" => $review, "weightloss" => $weightloss, "gained" => $gained);

    echo json_encode($AuthMeta);

    exit;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.author').click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            action: 'student_meta_info',
            studentID: id,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data)
            {
                var review = data.review;
                var weightloss = data.weightloss;
                var gained = data.gained;

                alert(data);
                alert(review);
                alert(weightloss);
                alert(gained);
            }
        });     
    });
});
```

Comment: Not an answer, but seeing as you're not fetching that much information I'd consider printing everything on page load and just toggle visibility with JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the WordPress AJAX url, right after `dataType`:

```
url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
```

To get the url as a var, you'll have to [localize your script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), example:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so16523111_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
function so16523111_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20130513', true );
    // in javascript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

Also, wrap the data to send as a data parameter...

```
data: {action:'student_meta_info',studentID:id},
```

... and use `response` to check if successful:

```
success: function(response)
```

Furthermore, you'll need to adjust the callback, and the ajax hooks to reflect the action:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_student_meta_info', 'get_student_meta_info' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_student_meta_info', 'get_student_meta_info' );
```

Lastly, you'll have to use jQuery in noconflict mode:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, getting a bug now. I'm getting all null values now. To make sure, where do I add the php to localize my script? Right now, its in the header. Worked once, then broke. So, where do I put it?

Comment: the enqueue + localize function should go in the `functions.php` file of your WP theme

Answer (score 0):

In the functions.php file, you didn't attach the hook to the right function (is `get_student_meta_info`, not `student_meta_info`):

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request', 'get_student_meta_info' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_request', 'get_student_meta_info' );
```

In the JavaScript code (AJAX call):

```
var data_to_send: {
    action: 'ajax_request', // This is how you call it in the add_action hooks
    studentID: id,
    ...
}

$.ajax({
    data: data_to_sent,
    success: function(r) { ... }
});
```

Hope it helps.